# SQL PIVOT(?) query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, pivot, pivot-without-aggregate

I have spent a full day on this and just don't get it. Usually I am pretty good with this stuff but I am just getting back in to SQL and just cannot figure this out. Any help you can provide would be very much appreciated.

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a database where I keep patient data (no names, just identifiers) and clinical test results. I have put together a view to query the various data tables and collect the information I need into one spot. The results of my query give me a table like this: (Tests and values are made up - I know nothing about the tests. I'm just the tech - lol.)

```
PtName   |  Age  |  Race  |  Ethnicity    |  DrawDate   |  TestType   | TestResult
PT001    |  17   |  White |  Non-Hispanic |  05/17/2011 |  WBC        | 6.8
PT001    |  17   |  White |  Non-Hispanic |  05/17/2011 |  HGB        | 14.1
PT001    |  17   |  White |  Non-Hispanic |  05/17/2011 |  Platelets  | 142.0
PT001    |  17   |  White |  Non-Hispanic |  05/29/2011 |  WBC        | 7.2
PT002    |  34   |  White |  Hispanic     |  05/17/2011 |  WBC        | 7.8
PT002    |  34   |  White |  Hispanic     |  05/17/2011 |  Platelets  | 255.0
```

What I want is:

```
PtName   |  Age  |  Race  |  Ethnicity    |  DrawDate   |  WBC  |  HGB  |  Platelets
PT001    |  17   |  White |  Non-Hispanic |  05/17/2011 |  6.8  |  14.1 |  142.0
PT001    |  17   |  White |  Non-Hispanic |  05/29/2011 |  7.2  |       |     
PT002    |  34   |  White |  Hispanic     |  05/17/2011 |       |       |  255.0
```

I worked out a PIVOT query (first one - very proud, didn't work - not so proud) but then realized that using the aggregate in the PIVOT query would not give me multiple visits for each patient.

I am dealing with hundreds of patients, some have multiple visits, with up to eight tests each. Is a PIVOT query the best way to deal with this? Is there a better way? Some form of subquery perhaps? I am willing to try about anything.

Comment: Can you show the tables (columns associated to get the result) for the final pivot you are trying?  It is relatively easy once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Although this can be done using pivot (see this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9ed2/5/0), I recommend that you solve the problem in the front-end (HTML or XAML) where can deal with the data easily.

Comment: Are the test values known ahead of time or are you going to have an unlimited number of tests?

Answer (score 2):

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable (PtName NVARCHAR(20),Age INT,Race NVARCHAR(30),Ethnicity NVARCHAR(50)
                        ,DrawDate DATE, TestType NVARCHAR(50), TestResult NUMERIC(20,1))
GO
INSERT INTO #myTable
VALUES
('PT001',17,'White','Non-Hispanic','05/17/2011','WBC',6.8),
('PT001',17,'White','Non-Hispanic','05/17/2011','HGB',14.1),
('PT001',17,'White','Non-Hispanic','05/17/2011','Platelets',142.0),
('PT001',17,'White','Non-Hispanic','05/29/2011','WBC',7.2),
('PT002',34,'White','Hispanic','05/17/2011','WBC',7.8),
('PT002',34,'White','Hispanic','05/17/2011','Platelets',255.0)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT PtName, Age, Race, Ethnicity, DrawDate, [WBC], [HGB], [Platelets]
FROM (SELECT * FROM #myTable)t
  PIVOT (
         MAX(TestResult)
         FOR TestType
         IN ([WBC], [HGB], [Platelets])
         )p
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════╦═════╦═══════╦══════════════╦════════════╦═════╦══════╦═══════════╗
║ PtName ║ Age ║ Race  ║  Ethnicity   ║  DrawDate  ║ WBC ║ HGB  ║ Platelets ║
╠════════╬═════╬═══════╬══════════════╬════════════╬═════╬══════╬═══════════╣
║ PT001  ║  17 ║ White ║ Non-Hispanic ║ 2011-05-17 ║ 6.8 ║ 14.1 ║ 142.0     ║
║ PT001  ║  17 ║ White ║ Non-Hispanic ║ 2011-05-29 ║ 7.2 ║ NULL ║ NULL      ║
║ PT002  ║  34 ║ White ║ Hispanic     ║ 2011-05-17 ║ 7.8 ║ NULL ║ 255.0     ║
╚════════╩═════╩═══════╩══════════════╩════════════╩═════╩══════╩═══════════╝
```

Comment: I was able to get this working using a variation of your suggestion. I had tried something similar before but must have been missing the magic piece. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have made something like this:

```
SELECT 
x.PtName,
x.Age,
x.Race,
x.Ethnicity,
x.DrawDate, 
(
    SELECT y.TestResult
    FROM `TABLE 1` as `y` 
    WHERE x.TestType = 'WBC' 
    AND x.PtName = y.PtName
    AND x.DrawDate = y.DrawDate
    LIMIT 1
) AS 'WBC',
(
    SELECT z.TestResult
    FROM `TABLE 1` as `z` 
    WHERE z.TestType = 'HGB' 
    AND x.PtName = z.PtName
    AND x.DrawDate = z.DrawDate
    LIMIT 1
) AS 'HGB',
(
    SELECT v.TestResult
    FROM `TABLE 1` as `v` 
    WHERE v.TestType = 'Platelets' 
    AND x.PtName = v.PtName
    AND x.DrawDate = v.DrawDate
    LIMIT 1
) AS 'Platelets'
FROM `TABLE 1` as `x`
GROUP BY PtName, DrawDate
```

I'm sure this is not very fast, but it works at least for me ;)

Comment: the question has `SQL-SERVER` tag NOT `mysql`

Comment: I was able to get this working using a variation of the first suggestion above. I had tried something similar before but must have been missing the magic piece. Thank you so much for trying to help me though!